# Select rows after certain condition

Tags: awk

Select rows after the maximum minimum valor found

Input file

```
22 101 5
23 102 5
24 103 5
25 104 23
26 105 25
27 106 21
28 107 20
29 108 8
30 109 6
31 110 7
```

To figure out my problem, I tried to subtract column 3 and print the lines after the minimum value found in column 4. In this case after row 7

```
awk '{$4 = $3 - prev3; prev3 = $3; print $0}' file

22 101 5 
23 102 5 0
24 103 5 0
25 104 2 18
26 105 2 2
27 106 2 -4
28 107 2 -1
29 108 8 -12
30 109 6 -2
31 110 7 1
```

**Desired Output**

```
29 108 8
30 109 6
31 110 7
```

I believe there is better and easy way to get same output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your problem description? Does it have to be after the minimum *and* the maximum have been found? Is `valor` a typo and do you mean `value`, or is it a specific term (if so, please explain). Do the first and second row have any meaning or use here?

Comment: Not clear, you mention in your column 4 logic `+` addition but you re writing it subtraction? Also not clear which maximum and minimum values are you talking? column 4 or column3? Please edit your post with correct samples and get back to us then.

Comment: What should happen if there are just two rows, like: `22 101 5 <newline>
23 102 7` for example? Should both rows be printed or just the last one (what is the default value of "0th" row)?

Comment: Given the output and the values in column four, I'm guessing "the maximum minimum valor" means the maximum *negative* value of the difference between two consecutive rows. But that will have to be clarified by the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to process the same file twice:

1. Find out the line number of the min value
2. Print the line and the lines after it

Like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{v=$3-prev3;prev3=$3;if(NR==2||v<m){m=v;ln=NR};next}FNR>=ln' file file
```

Explanation:

```
# This condition is true as long as we process the file the first time
NR==FNR {

    # Your calculation
    v=$3-prev3
    prev3=$3

    # If NR==2, meaning in row 2 we initialize m and ln.
    # Otherwise check if v is the new minimum and set m and ln.
    if(NR==2 || v<m){
        # Set m and ln when v is the new minimum
        m=v
        ln=NR
    }

    next # Skip the conditional below
}

# This condition will be only evaluated when we parse the file
# the second time. (because of the "next" statement above)

# When the line number is greater or equal than "ln" print it.
# (print is the default action)
FNR>=ln
```

Comment: thanks :) ... It was simpler to understand when executing what the OP had (and change `+` to `-`)

Comment: That will fail if/when all the $3 values are greater than their predecessor. Try it with input where $3 is 2, 3, 4, etc.. You need to add a condition to populate m and ln when m is null, not just when m is less than v or you'll be relying on the value of `v` becoming negative at some point to cause m to be set for the first time. It's like any other min/max calculation - you've **got** to use the initial value as the min/max.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks!

Comment: No problem and you do not need to init m and ln - awk does that for you and does it in a better way than that by using zero-or-null so you can differentiate first use from a specific numeric value. Just get rid of all the stuff about initing m and ln and change `if(v<m){` to `if (NR==2 || v<m) {` (assuming the OP doesn't want to compare the first $3 to 0) and you're good to go!

Comment: Sounds much better. Will change that (later, atm working)